# JNI convert result of CallObjectMethod to unsigned short

Tags: c, java-native-interface

After CallObjectMethod, I should have an object which real type is jchar, and how can I change this object to unsigned short in C++.

Now I tried cast object to jchar then cast jchar to unsigned short but got

```
error: cast from 'jobject {aka _jobject*}' to 'jchar {aka short unsigned int}' loses precision [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: If it returns a char then why aren't you using `CallCharMethod`?

Comment: CallObjectMethod(object, method) returns a object not a char, but my method returns char, so I want to know how to get the result of my method

Comment: Exactly... `CallObjectMethod` clearly doesn't work here, so why are you trying to use it? See EJP's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After CallObjectMethod, I should have an object which real type is jchar

No you won't. The result of that method is an `Object.` If the actual Java method you're calling returns a `char,` you should call `CallCharMethod().`

> and how can I change this object to unsigned short in C++.

It's only an object if you call the wrong method.

Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: What if I want `CallObjectMethod` to return a custom C++ class?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky It returns a Java object. Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I was wondering if it's possible to cast a Java object to C++ object.

Comment: The Java object is opaque. You can only get inside it via JNI methods. If your C++ class has a suitable constructor that does all that, sure, but it would be a strange thing to build into a C++ class.